# How to close an file opended with pdfquery, it is blocking the pdf-file?

Tags: python, pdf

I try to rename pdf files opended with pdfquery, extracting the name for the pdf file out of the data. pdfquery locks the file and prevent renaming. There is no close method to unlock the file.

I tried to 'del pdf' and force to close the file before renaming, but it is not working. (tried on windows, dont know if linux works)

```
import os
import pdfquery


def is_pdf(file):
    if os.path.splitext(file.lower())[1] == '.pdf':
        return True


pdf_files = os.listdir('./pages')
for pdf_file in filter(is_pdf, pdf_files):
    if is_pdf(pdf_file):
        print(pdf_file)
        pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery(os.path.join('pages', pdf_file))
        pdf.load()
        for e in pdf.tree.iter():
            text = e.text
            if text:
                text = text.replace(' ', '')
                if text[0:7] == '4002629':
                    #del pdf
                    os.rename(os.path.join('pages', pdf_file), '{}.pdf'.format(text))
```

Expecting a renamed file, but get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PDFs_aufbereiten\pdf_pages_rename.py", line 22, in <module>
    os.rename(os.path.join('pages', pdf_file), '{}.pdf'.format(text))
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird: 'pages\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf' -> 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf'
```

Comment: make a copy, rename copy file and then save it, delete original one

Comment: I will do it if there is no other solution. Thanks

Comment: why not just directly rename file ?

Comment: My description was not clear, i changed it. I getting the name for the pdf, out of the pdf itself.

Comment: ** Same code on linux is working ** So it is an windows only problem.
So i going to report the bug to pdfquery.

Comment: build a dict of `{existing_filename:new_filename}` and do the renaming outside of your loop?

Comment: With a dict i have the same problem, i tried time.sleep and wait a minute, files still locked. With process explorer i see they still locked after the program finished, they are freed only after python.exe/pythonw.exe are closed.

I cannot guess where this problem comes from now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
pdf.file.close()
```

Comment: I think you could expand your answer to indicate *where* in the code the file should be closed. Especially as the problem is mainly related to *where* the `os.rename` is.

Answer (score 0):

The code works on linux, so pdfquery or a used module by pdfquery is causing the error on windows only. I opened an issue on https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery/issues/75 and update this post if i get a fix or workaround.

**Workaround** open/close the file by own code before using pdfquery.PDFQuery (thanks to nedbat):

```
import os
import pdfquery


def is_pdf(file):
    if os.path.splitext(file.lower())[1] == '.pdf':
        return True


rename_files = []
pdf_files = os.listdir('./pages')
for pdf_file in filter(is_pdf, pdf_files):
    print(pdf_file)
    with open(os.path.join('pages', pdf_file), 'rb') as myfile:
        pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery(myfile)
        pdf.load()
        for e in pdf.tree.iter():
            text = e.text
            if text:
                text = text.replace(' ', '')
                if text[0:7] == '4002629':
                    rename_files.append(
                        (pdf_file, '{}.pdf'.format(text))
                    )
                    break

for oldname, newname in rename_files:
    os.rename(os.path.join('pages', oldname),
              os.path.join('pages', newname)
              )
```